# Is it possible to select rows by 1 column value(user_id) if it have more then 1 rows with column value(status: "active") in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have some users functional where one user can have many settings, but ONLY ONE active.
And I need a cron check if there is any users with 2 or more "active" status

DB example:

| ID | USER_ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2775 | 'active' |
| 2 | 4851 | 'inactive' |
| 3 | 3333 | 'active' |
| 4 | 3333 | 'inactive' |
| 5 | 3333 | 'active' |
| 6 | 1575 | 'active' |
| 7 | 8151 | 'inactive' |
| 8 | 4444 | 'inactive' |
| 9 | 4444 | 'active' |
| 10 | 4444 | 'active' |

So I need a SELECT that gonna return rows 3, 5, 9, 10

| ID | USER_ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3333 | 'active' |
| 5 | 3333 | 'active' |
| 9 | 4444 | 'active' |
| 10 | 4444 | 'active' |

Any help ?

Comment: Create according unique constraint based on generated column which does not allow more than one `'active'` row per user.

Comment: Why not avoid getting into such a situation?

Comment: by the use cases there can be more then 1 active per user, but not long time (less than a second in a happy flow)

Comment: Alter your "use case", revert it to "no active per user for one second". And add a constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer myself already.

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`
where status = 'active'
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

actually it will return only one grouped row per user_id, but that's will do.